# monitoring keepalived with snmp

Tags: snmp, keepalived, snmpd

I am trying to monitor keepalived with snmp. Here are the relevant part of the config:
/etc/snmp/snmp.conf

```
# As the snmp packages come without MIB files due to license reasons, loading
# of MIBs is disabled by default. If you added the MIBs you can reenable
# loading them by commenting out the following line.
#mibs :
mibs +KEEPALIVED-MIB
```

/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

```
master agentx
#agentXSocket udp:127.0.0.1:705
#agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161

rocommunity public 127.0.0.1

trapcommunity public 
trap2sink 127.0.0.1
```

/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf

```
global_defs {
  notification_email {
  enable_snmp_checker  ops@example.com
  }
  notification_email_from ops@example.com
  smtp_server localhost
  smtp_connect_timeout 60
  #snmp_socket udp:127.0.0.1:705
  #enable_snmp_checker
  #enable_snmp_rfcv3
  #enable_snmp_rfcv2
  #enable_snmp_vrrp
  #enable_snmp_rfc
  #enable_traps
}
...
...
```

ll /usr/share/snmp/mibs/

```
total 216
drwxr-xr-x 2 user user   4096 Sep 12 10:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4096 Sep 12 10:55 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 143802 Sep 12 10:56 KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  26693 Sep 12 10:56 VRRP-MIB.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  34959 Sep 12 10:56 VRRPv3-MIB.txt
```

keepalived is working and running for a while now with `-x` in `/etc/default/keepalived`. But the snmp doesn't work. I am using the mibs files from [acassen/keepalived](https://github.com/acassen/keepalived). When I run the following:

```
# snmpwalk -v 2c -c public 127.0.0.1 KEEPALIVED-MIB
```

I get:

```
MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (MTA-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NETWORK-SERVICES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DISKIO-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DLMOD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (LM-SENSORS-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-SNMP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UCD-DEMO-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-TARGET-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-ICMP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IPV6-UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-FORWARD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TM): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-VACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 13 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (INET-ADDRESS-MIB): At line 18 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 20 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TC): At line 22 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt
Did not find 'enterprises' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'InetAddressType' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'InetAddress' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'InetPortNumber' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'InetAddressPrefixLength' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'InetScopeType' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'InterfaceIndex' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'ifIndex' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'DisplayString' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt)
Did not find 'TruthValue' in module #-1 (/usr/share/snmp/mibs/KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt)
Unlinked OID in KEEPALIVED-MIB: debian ::= { enterprises 9586 }
Undefined identifier: enterprises near line 149 of /usr/share/snmp/mibs/KEEPALIVED-MIB.txt
Cannot adopt OID in KEEPALIVED-MIB: vrrpRouteEntry ::= { vrrpRouteTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in KEEPALIVED-MIB: vrrpTrapControl ::= { vrrpTrap 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in KEEPALIVED-MIB: vrrpTraps ::= { vrrpTrap 0 }
Cannot adopt OID in KEEPALIVED-MIB: vrrpSyncTrackedScriptEntry ::= { vrrpSyncTrackedScriptTable 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in KEEPALIVED-MIB: vrrpTrackedBfdWgtRev ::= { vrrpTrackedBfdEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in KEEPALIVED-MIB: vrrpTrackedBfdWeight ::= { vrrpTrackedBfdEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in KEEPALIVED-MIB: vrrpTrackedBfdName ::= { vrrpTrackedBfdEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in KEEPALIVED-MIB: vrrpTrackedBfdIndex ::= { vrrpTrackedBfdEntry 1 }
...
...
KEEPALIVED-MIB: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> KEEPALIVED-MIB)
```

I tried different configurations for keepalived and snmpd, unfortunately none worked. 
This is a Linux host running Ubuntu Xenial:
uname -a

```
Linux vgw01 4.20.0-custom #45 SMP Tue Dec 25 13:33:11 CET 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

snmpd -v

```
NET-SNMP version:  5.7.3
Web:               http://www.net-snmp.org/
Email:             net-snmp-coders@lists.sourceforge.net
```

Keepalived -v

```
Keepalived v2.0.12 (unknown)

Copyright(C) 2001-2019 Alexandre Cassen, <acassen@gmail.com>

Built with kernel headers for Linux 4.4.162
Running on Linux 4.20.0-custom #45 SMP Tue Dec 25 13:33:11 CET 2018

configure options: --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking --enable-snmp --enable-sha1 --enable-snmp-rfcv2 --enable-snmp-rfcv3 --enable-dbus --enable-dbus-create-instance --enable-json --enable-bfd --enable-nftables build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2

Config options:  LIBIPTC LIBIPSET_DYNAMIC NFTABLES LVS VRRP VRRP_AUTH JSON BFD OLD_CHKSUM_COMPAT FIB_ROUTING SNMP_V3_FOR_V2 SNMP_VRRP SNMP_CHECKER SNMP_RFCV2 SNMP_RFCV3 DBUS DBUS_CREATE_INSTANCE

System options:  PIPE2 SIGNALFD INOTIFY_INIT1 VSYSLOG EPOLL_CREATE1 IPV4_DEVCONF IPV6_ADVANCED_API LIBNL3 RTA_ENCAP RTA_NEWDST RTA_PREF FRA_SUPPRESS_PREFIXLEN FRA_SUPPRESS_IFGROUP FRA_TUN_ID RTAX_CC_ALGO RTAX_QUICKACK RTEXT_FILTER_SKIP_STATS RTA_VIA FRA_OIFNAME IFA_FLAGS IP_MULTICAST_ALL LWTUNNEL_ENCAP_MPLS LWTUNNEL_ENCAP_ILA LIBIPTC LIBIPSET_PRE_V7 NET_LINUX_IF_H_COLLISION LIBIPVS_NETLINK IPVS_DEST_ATTR_ADDR_FAMILY IPVS_SYNCD_ATTRIBUTES IPVS_64BIT_STATS VRRP_VMAC CN_PROC SOCK_NONBLOCK SOCK_CLOEXEC O_PATH GLOB_BRACE INET6_ADDR_GEN_MODE VRF SO_MARK SCHED_RT SCHED_RESET_ON_FORK
```

Later on I'll be monitoring it with check_mk. Do you have any idea how I can make it work?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are missing the "default" MIBs. Try `apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader`

Comment: Hi, I had the package installed, but it doesn't provide the keepalived mibs, never the less I installed it again and still have the same problem:
`KEEPALIVED-MIB: Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> KEEPALIVED-MIB)`

Comment: Uncomment this line `#mibs :` in `/etc/snmp/snmp.conf`, you are not loading your default MIBs.

Comment: I did. Still the same error. I was juggling with the config in all possible combinations to see the impact of it. I also have this line in `syslog` ` Keepalived_vrrp[8285]: Warning: Failed to connect to the agentx master agent ([NIL]):` when I comment the `snmp_socket` line in `keepalived.conf` and starting it with `-x`. When I comment it out with the `agentXSocket` in `snmpd.conf`, I don't see the socket with `ss -l -a`, further more it seems like keepalived cannot connect to tcp socket if I change it to `tcp`. I may need an example config of `keepalived.conf` `snmpd.conf` to make them work

Comment: I found this thread, but it is not working foe me:
http://www.jiajianhudong.com/question/2319171.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems that snmpd on Ubuntu Xenial has a bug, the agentx dowsn't start even if it is specified in the `snmpd.conf`. I had to specifiy it in `/etc/default/snmpd` and I can totally omit it in `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` so that I have only one line in the file. Here is the working configurations for me:

`/etc/default/snmpd`

```
SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -g snmp -p /run/snmpd.pid --master=agentx --agentXSocket=tcp:localhost:705'
```

`/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf`

```
rocommunity public monitoring.server
```

`/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf`

```
global_defs {
  notification_email {
  enable_snmp_checker  ops@example.com
  }
  notification_email_from ops@example.com
  smtp_server localhost
  smtp_connect_timeout 60
  snmp_socket tcp:localhost:705 
  enable_snmp_checker
  enable_snmp_rfcv3
  enable_snmp_rfcv2
  enable_snmp_vrrp
  enable_snmp_rfc
  #enable_traps
}
```

`/etc/default/keepalived`

```
DAEMON_ARGS="-D --snmp"`
```

Thanks Lenniey for you suggestions